# Timestamp inserted in DolphinDB does not match expectations

Tags: timestamp, timezone, dolphindb

The timestamp I insert is timestamp(1656898205942), which should be 2022/7/4 9:30:5.942. However, in DolphinDB it shows 2022/7/4 1:30:5.942. It looks like a time zone problem. Can anyone tell me how to obtain the expected timestamp？

Answer (score 1):

Temporal data are stored without time zone in DolphinDB. 1656898205942 is a Unix timestamp indicating UTC time 2022/7/4 1:30:5.942, which is interpreted as 2022/7/4 1:30:5.942 in DolphinDB. Therefore, you can add a time zone converter when storing the temporal data with function `localtime` or adding the offset.

For example, to convert the time to **UTC+08:00**:

```
localtime(timestamp(1656898205942))
```

The timestamp is thus interpreted as:

```
2022.07.04T09:30:05.942
```